# Show that if $f(x)=o(|x-x_0|)$, then $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$.

Tags: real-analysis

A function is differentiable at $x_0$ if for all $\epsilon$ there exists $\delta$ such that $|x-x_0| < \delta \implies |\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0} - f'(x_0)| < \epsilon$.

Using little o notation, a function is differentiable at $x_0$ iff
$$f(x)=f'(x_0)(x-x_0)+f(x_0)+o(|x-x_0|)$$

---

Since $f(x)=o(|x-x_0|)$ then for all $\epsilon$ there exists $\delta$ such that $|x-x_o| < \delta \implies |f(x)| \le \epsilon|x-x_0|$. So, $|f(x)/(x-x_0)| \le \epsilon$.

How do I get out of this that $f$ is differentiable?

Answer (score 1):

First argue that $f(x_{0})=0$, and then you are ready to see that $f'(x_{0})=0$.

Comment: As $x \to x_0$ then $|f(x)| \to 0$? If this is true, then from this, can we say $f(x_0)=0$?

Comment: From the assertion that any $x$ with $|x-x_{0}|<\delta|$ will imply $|f(x)|\leq\epsilon|x-x_{0}|$, just plug in $x=x_{0}$.

Comment: Does little o notation allow for this? Isn't it as $x \to x_0$?

Comment: Then can you show me your definition of little-o? As far as I searched the web the notation, it goes through.

Comment: It must be in this case for the definition of little-o, if not, consider the discontinuous function at $x=1$ with $f(x)=0$ on a neighbourhood of $x=1$ but $f(1)=2$, then $|f(x)|\leq\epsilon|x-1|$ for all $x\ne 1$.

Comment: But in your example, if you plug in $1$, then we get $2 \le 0$.

Comment: I am saying that in your question of little-o definition, we can plug in $x=x_{0}$, if this is not allowed, then I have come out with an example that is discontinuous (so not differentiable) that satisfying prohibited plugging in little-o version.

Comment: Shouldn't the example be of a differentiable function such that plugging in is prohibited?

Comment: I don't quite follow? My example of course is not differentiable at $x=1$.

Comment: I don't understand your counterexample. What does it show?

Comment: Okay, let us summarize here. In your question, why $f(x_{0})=0$? It is simply plugging in $x=x_{0}$ into $|f(x)|\leq\epsilon|x-x_{0}|$, and plugging in is allowed, that's it.